# I don't know how to find a plane set up by two known vectors, and then change the base of another vector (in that plane) into the two other vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Show that vector $w=(3, 0, -1)$ is positioned in the plane that is set up by $u= (1, 2, 1)$ and $v= (2, 1, 0)$. Provide the coordinates for $w$ expressed in the base $\{u,v\}$ as well.

How do I answer the question? I know that if I use the linear combination of the vectors I can show that vectors $w,u,v$ are complanar. However, for the second question, I also need to provide coordinates for $w$ in that plane, which I don't even know how to begin with.

Comment: Could you check all the vectors are written correctly because these 3 vectors are linearly independent

Comment: @Butane, my apologies. I have corrected the question!

Comment: When in doubt, go back to basic definitions: what does it mean for a set of numbers to be the coordinates of a vector relative to some basis?

Answer (score 0):

If you could write $w = 17u + (-3)v$, for instance, then the answer to the second part would be "in the $u,v$-coordinate system, the coordinates of $w$ are $17$ and $-3$."

So if you manage to answer the first part (using "I know that if I use the linear combination of the vectors I can show that vector $$ is indeed in a plane of $$ and $$") then you'll have solved the second part as well.

Comment: Okay! So, there could be many different answers, but it's best to use the one that is "smallest" right? I mean the multiple 1. Thank you so much!

Comment: In this case, because $u$ and $v$ are not parallel, there's exactly *one* pair of coefficients $(a,b)$ that make $w = au + b v$; you still need to *find* those, of course...